# Moving hibernate properties configuration file outside of project?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, datasource, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to move a `hibernate` configuration file containing the db connection details outside of the hibernate project and connect to it?

My current configuration is as follows, but I would like to move my file from outside the project and still connect to my `data sources`. How can I do so?

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({"classpath:hibernate.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.my.packages", entityManagerFactoryRef = "schemaOneManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "schemaOneTransactionManager")
public class SchemaOneDataSourceConfig
{

//configuration methods

}
```

Do I need to make a change to line: `@PropertySource({"classpath:hibernate.properties"})` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the JavaDocs of `PropertySource`

> Indicate the resource location(s) of the properties file to be loaded. For example, "classpath:/com/myco/app.properties" or "file:/path/to/file".

You just need to change a prefix to `file:`

```
@PropertySource({"file:/path/to/hibernate.properties"})
```

Comment: thanks, are the double \\ characters needed to escape the chars in the string?

Comment: @java123999 Just use `/` instead of \\.

Comment: When I do this I get "class path resource  cannot be opened because it does not exist" ? thanks

Comment: @java123999 It should work. Do you remove `classpath:`?

Comment: error: class path resource cannot be opened because it does not exist ?

Comment: I am using intelij? I do not know how it is specified, do I need to add this file to my classpath?

Comment: @java123999 I think, no. What exactly you specify in place of this `file:/path/to/hibernate.properties`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot, you can put the properties in `application.properties` and you can have that file in your JAR, but also override it by putting it in a `config` sub-folder (relative to your running directory).

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files for more info.